# Шифрование текста методом Квадрата Полибия в С++

Tags: c++builder, шифрование, c++

Нужно сделать программу, которая шифрует слово методом Квадрата Полибия.
Сначала предлагается количество букв из которых будет состоять ключ для шифрования. Например 5. Далее вводим слово из пяти букв. Буквы из этого слова убираются с места где они стояли в алфавите и переносятся на перед. Это я сделал( смотрим код). Вводим слово для шифрования.
Но нужно теперь зашифровать введенное слово. Делается это следующим образом. Буква из слова для шифрования сравнивается с положением той же буквы в алфавите и сдвигается на 5 букв назад, то есть вправо. Помогите реализовать.

Код

```
void main()
{
    char alpha[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int n=strlen(alpha);
    char *alph_kl=new char[n];
    int m;
    cout<<"Enter length of key word"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    char *w=new char[m];
    int z=n-m;
    cout<<"n="<<n<<"m="<<m<<"z="<<z<<endl;
    char *alpha_bez=new char[z];
    cout<<"Enter key word"<<endl;
    gets(w);
    bool pr;
    for (int i=0,k=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        pr=false;
        for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
            if (alpha[i]==w[j])
            {
                pr=true;
                break;
            }
        if(pr==false) 
        {
            alpha_bez[k]=alpha[i];          
            k++;
        }
    }
    strcpy(alpha,w);
    for (i=m;i<n;i++)
        alpha[i]=alpha_bez[i-m];
    puts(alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько способов шифрования по [квадрату Полибия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%8F). Способ, который вам нужен, — это частный случай [шифра Цезаря](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F), со сдвигом, равным длине стороны квадрата.

Для начала проиллюстрируем сам алгоритм (*я использовал алфавит с кодовым словом «word»)*:

*Допустим, нам нужно зашифровать слово «UFO». Тогда мы сделаем следующее: найдем нужную букву на квадрате и заменим ее на букву, которая стоит ниже. Если нужная буква стоит в нижней строке, заменяем ее на самую верхнюю:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Для расшифровки делаем все наоборот.*

#### Реализация

В таком случае удобно хранить квадрат в виде одномерного массива символов:

```
char square[] = "wordabcefghiklmnpqstuvxyz";
```

Функция шифрования:

```
void encrypt(char* msg, const char* square, size_t square_side) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(msg); ++i) {
        const size_t index = strchr_get_index(square, msg[i]);
        msg[i] = square[(index + square_side) % strlen(square)];
    }
}
```

Функция дешифровки:

```
void decrypt(char* msg, const char* square, size_t square_side) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(msg); ++i) {
        /* Координата может получиться отрицательной. Это значит, что нужный
           нам символ находится в конце массива. */
        const int coord = strchr_get_index(square, msg[i]) - square_side;
        const size_t index = (coord >= 0) ? coord : strlen(square) + coord;
        msg[i] = square[index];
    }
}
```